# Is this proof of indepencence of two events circular?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Task (I freely admit it is from a former test):

We choose a random person $X$ and it turns out that this person has three siblings, with at least one older sister among them.

**A)** What is the probability that $X$ is a girl?

**B)** What is the probability that the second oldest child of this familily is a girl?

**C)** What is the probability that $X$ is the youngest child of this family?

**D)** Let $A$, $B$, $C$ denote the above events. Which pairs are independent: $(A, B)$, $(A, C)$, $(B, C)$? Validate each answer.

Note: Assume that, regarding each birth, the events: *a boy is born* and *a girl is born* have the same probability $p=\frac12$ (we do not take into account the possibility of twins being born, etc), and these events are independent from any former births.

## My solution attempt:

**A)** $\frac12$, from the independence of birhts.

Before we go to B), C), D), let's list all legal combinations:

- If $X$ is the second oldest kid: $b/g\quad b/g\quad X_{b/g}\quad g$ - this gives $8$ combinations
- If $X$ is the third oldest kid: $b/g \quad X_{b/g}\quad b/g \quad b/g$ - this would be $4\cdot 4$ combinations, but we must exclude the illegal combination that two oldest kids are all boys, so it's $4\cdot 3 = 12$ combinations
- If $X$ is the youngest kid: $X_{b/g} \quad b/g \quad b/g \quad b/g$ - Excluding the illegal combination that all older kids are all boys this gives us $2\cdot7=14$ combinations

So we have a total of $34$ legal combinations.

**B)** Let's list legal combinations:

- $b/g\quad b/g\quad X_g \quad g$ - $4$ combinations
- $b/g \quad X_{b/g} \quad g \quad b/g$ - $8$ combinations
- $X_{b/g} \quad b/g \quad g \quad b/g$ - $8$ combinations

Thus the probability is $\frac{4+8+8}{34}=\frac{10}{17}$

**C)** Above we showed that there are $14$ legal combinations in such a case, so the answer is $\frac{14}{34}=\frac{7}{17}$

**D)** And here be dragons, I guess.

This is how I'd tackle this:

$(A, B)$:

All legal combinations for the event $A\cap B$ are:

- $b/g\quad b/g \quad X_g \quad g$ - $4$ combinations
- $b/g \quad X_g \quad g \quad b/g$ - $4$ combinations
- $X_g\quad b/g\quad g\quad b/g$ - $4$ combinations

$12$ combinations total, so $P(A\cap B) = \frac {12}{34} \neq \frac12\cdot \frac{20}{34} = P(A)\cdot P(B)$, so by definition $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

$(A,C)$: There are $7$ legal combinations for the event $A\cap C$: $X_g\quad b/g \quad b/g \quad b/g$, this would be $8$ but we must exclude the illegal combination $X_g \quad b \quad b \quad b$

Therefore $P(A\cap C) = \frac7{34} = \frac12 \cdot \frac {14}{34} = P(A)\cdot P(B)$, so by definition these events are independent

$(B, C)$: THere are $8$ legal combinations: $X_{b/g} \quad b/g \quad g \quad b/g$

So we have $P(B\cap C) = \frac8{34} = \frac 4{17}$
But $P(B)\cdot P(C) = \frac7{17}\cdot \frac{10}{17} \neq \frac 4{17}$

So by definition these events are not independent.

## My worry is:

I used the classical definition of probability for each part of the task. But I can only use the classical definition if the permutation of children in this famility is independent of their sex; so, essentialy, I can only use the classical definition if $(A, C)$ are independent. However, it was my task to prove that $A$ and $C$ are really independent, and I used the classical definition to prove it... So, in the end, am I not guilty of circular reasoning here?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is okay and not circular is the subtlety of *how person $X$ is selected*, and what information we have available about them.

When you say that $X$ is selected a random, presumably you mean that they are chosen among the four children uniformly and independently of the sex of the children. If we didn't know anything about the older siblings of $X$, then you're right; $A$ and $C$ would be trivially independent of one another because of that assumption. Note that in this scenario, $(A, B)$ and $(B, C)$ would also be independent for essentially this same trivial reason.

But in this case, we have some extra information -- call it event $E$ -- that $X$ has an older sister. Now, the problem is secretly to compute $P(A \mid E), P(B \mid E), P(C \mid E)$ and to assess their independence on one another. The computation you actually did was $P(A \cap C \mid E) = P(A \mid E) \cdot P(C \mid E)$. If this was indeed just a trivial application of the principle that the permutation is independent of the sex, then I claim that the other events would have been independent as well. Instead, what you did was an explicit calculation on the *conditioned* probability space (this was the act where you removed illegal combinations from consideration) and verified the conditional independence.

**In short, it's not circular because you redid the calculation with the denominator of 34.**

I think where you're getting hung up is that you have a strong intuitive sense 
that $A$ and $C$ should remain independent of one another even with the additional information provided. And you're right, of course; but you didn't rely on that intuition to show it. Instead, you made a computation to verify it.

NB: I did not thoroughly check your computations, but they seemed fine at a glance.